# Cannot figure permutation in Python

Tags: python

i'm trying to find combination in numbers and here is how far I've gotten but i'm not sure about my mistake.

```
def perm1(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        return[lst]
    else:
        l = []
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            x = lst[i]
            xs = lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]
        for p in perm1(xs):
            l.append([x]+p)
        return l

data = list('1''2''3''4')
print 'perm1'
for p in perm1(data):
    print p
```

it prints

```
perm1
['4', '3', '2', '1']
```

and my goal is

```
[1,2] [2,3] [2,4][1,4] ect.
```

what do I need to do?

Comment: Well first of all this is not the correct syntax `list('1''2''3''4')` I think you mean to say `data = [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Also are you aware of the `itertools` library? They have a function `itertools.permutations` that will do this for you.

Comment: I tried to change my syntax but it still gave the same thing. I am not aware of the intertools library, i m fairly new at this. how do i use that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `itertools.permutations`

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4],2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4),
 (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4),
 (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4),
 (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code output all permutations of two elements :

```
import itertools

data = ['1','2','3','4']
res = [ [f, l] for f, l in itertools.product(data, repeat=2)]
```

`res` value is :

```
['1', '2']                                                                                                   
['1', '3']                                                                                                   
['1', '4']                                                                                                   
['2', '1']                                                                                                   
['2', '2']                                                                                                   
['2', '3'] 
(...)
```

Find [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) the documentation of itertools

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Your question title refers to permutations.  Your question speaks of combinations (not the same thing).  Your example output is either two-sets or a set product (again, different things).  If you want any of these you can:

```
from itertools import product, permutations, combinations
lst = [1,2,3,4]
print product(lst, repeat=2)  #set product
print permutations(lst, 2)  #2-permutations
print combinations(lst, 2)  #2-sets
```